# How to export the data from csv input and store the output data to a python class

Tags: python-3.x, csv, class

My requirement:

```
1. Read FairDealCustomerData.csv 
2. Name field contains full name – use regular expression to separate 
  title, first name, last name
3. Store the data in Customer Class instead of writing into new CSV
```

input CSV data:

```
Braund   Mr. Owen Harris        1
Heikkinen  Miss. Laina          0
Allen     Mr. William Henry     0
Moran     Mr. James             0
```

Expected output data THAT should store in python class:

```
Braund    Owen Harris    1  Mr'
Heikkinen Laina          0  Miss'
Allen     William Henry  0  Mr'
Moran     James          0  Mr'
```

this is my sample data @Reblochon Masque

I can able to export the output data to a new CSV but fed up with how to store that output data in a class

My code Input: CSV OUPUT: CSV :GOT THE RESULT

```
import csv
filename = "F:\\FairDealCustomerData.csv"
csvout = "F:\\FairDealCustomerDataout.csv"
with open(filename,'r',newline='') as read_file:
    readCSV = csv.reader(read_file, delimiter=',')
    with open(csvout,"w",newline='') as write_file:
        writer = csv.writer(write_file)
        for row in readCSV:
        writer.writerow([row[0], row[1].split('.')[1].strip() + ' ', 
        row[2], row[1].split('.')[0].strip()])
write_file.close()
```

Trying to store the data to python class:

I must store the output data from CSV input file to a CLASS.HOW CAN WE DO that?

Comment: please paste a small sample of some data rows in the csv file

Comment: @ReblochonMasque 
I have updated input data from CSV and expected data that should be stored in python class in the question above please have a look